# How to test which is scrolling HTML or Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

i try to replace scroll using my own way, but is there any way test which element (HTML or BODY) who able to scroll on browser using javascript (jQuery)?

i try to look both on DOM inspector, both of them have scrollTop attribute, but only one who able to change.

Comment: Why not just detect the scroll event on both elements?

Comment: how to check it? and how to test that element cannot do any scrolltop animation?

Comment: Please share the code you have so far, so we know what you actually need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if body or html scrolls if i get you right. Wouldn' this do the job for you:

```
$(window)
.on('scroll', 'html', function() {
    htmlScroll();
})
.on('scroll', 'body', function() {
    bodyScroll();
})
```